# Is it possible to have a private/internal docker repository?

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker and wanted to see where new images are uploaded to. I noticed that Docker hub also has a private section but it's still on their servers. Is it possible to have a local repository installed? if so how, what are they called?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run your own open-source registry, in fact you can run it [in a docker container](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/). Or you can buy an on-prem solution from Docker called Docker Trusted Registry.